# proper function to find out time elapsed since windows started?

Tags: .net-2.0

I know [Environment.TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) exist but I have a big problem with that, it's limited to 25 days.

what would be a good alternative that require no external module/dll and would work in a vanilla install of windows server 2003?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of choices.

```
public TimeSpan SystemUpTime()
{
    PerformanceCounter upTime = 
        new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time");

    // You've got to call this twice. First time it returns 0 
    // and the second time it returns the real info.
    upTime.NextValue();   
    return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(upTime.NextValue());
}
```

This, however, won't run if you don't have sufficient privileges.

You can also use [WMI](http://blogs.clearscreen.com/dtax/archive/2007/01/19/5985.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WMI` to get [`WIN32_OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(VS.85).aspx).